# How to do a minimal installation of Linux manually?

Tags: system-installation, distribution-choice, distributions, small-distribution

I'm looking for a guide on how to manually install Linux...
 
without the classic assisted setup... 
just by copying files from a source to a target media...
and configuring the minimum required settings.
(this is for educational purpouses)

> 1. creating partitions and formating the target drive...
> 2. copying the files minimum files from a source to the target drive (manual copy, file-by-file)
> 3. creating minimal required folders (/root /bin /etc ...)
> 4. creating minimum configuration files (/etc/???)
> 5. select and install a bootloader for MBR... and other for GPT/EFI

Any modern distro like Arch/Alpine/Kali/UBUNTU-Minimal/...

?can somebody point me to some document/video on this topic

Thanks

Comment: Gentoo might be close enough to what you're after: https://gentoo.org/

Comment: [Gentoo Handbook](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Full/Installation). Take a look.

Comment: [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) provides a guide on how to build a minimal Linux system from source code.

Comment: such good info... thanks guys..

Answer (score 2):

You can start with the boot images. Here are some with different names and sizes.

```
]# ls *.iso -dsh
607M OL-x86_64-boot-uek.iso
603M archlinux-2019.01.01-x86_64.iso
258M install-gentoo_minimal.iso
2.6G slackware64-14.2-install-dvd.iso
882M ubuntu-18.10-live-server-amd64.iso
```

Such an ISO-image can be loop mounted, even without `-o loop` (but with `mkdir MNTPOINT` first i.e. a directory):

```
]# mount install-gentoo_minimal.iso iso
mount: /root/sda1/LINUX/iso: WARNING: device write-protected, mounted read-only.

]# ls iso
README.txt  boot  gentoo.efimg  grub  image.squashfs  isolinux  livecd
```

These files are essential:

```
]# ls -lh iso/isolinux/gentoo* iso/gentoo.efimg iso/image.squashfs 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6.4M Jan  9  2019 iso/gentoo.efimg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 236M Jan  9  2019 iso/image.squashfs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.8M Jan  9  2019 iso/isolinux/gentoo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5.1M Jan  9  2019 iso/isolinux/gentoo.igz
```

**gentoo.efimg**

Again: `mount [-o loop] iso/gentoo.efimg img/` after creating a mountpoint (dir) e.g. "img/". Then you get:

```
]# file img/EFI/BOOT/*
img/EFI/BOOT/BOOTIA32.EFI: PE32 executable (EFI application) Intel 80386 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
img/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI:  PE32+ executable (EFI application) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
img/EFI/BOOT/grubia32.efi: PE32 executable (EFI application) Intel 80386 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
img/EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi:  PE32+ executable (EFI application) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
img/EFI/BOOT/mmia32.efi:   PE32 executable (EFI application) Intel 80386 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
img/EFI/BOOT/mmx64.efi:    PE32+ executable (EFI application) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
```

These are different variations of EFI bootloaders. An alternative is to use Uefi Shell (or MBR...). But here are `BOOTX64.EFI` et al.

**image.squashfs**

This is a `Squashfs filesystem` according to *extension* and `file` command. So you (loop) mount it just like an iso image.

It contains the files for the root partition.

```
]# ldd sq/bin/bash
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffe97ef000)
        libreadline.so.7 => not found
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0d4e221000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0d4e6c5000)
]# ./sq/bin/bash
./sq/bin/bash: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This shows that a normal /bin/bash also needs some libraries, and versions and links.

---

**iso/isolinux/gentoo**

```
]# file iso/isolinux/gentoo
iso/isolinux/gentoo: Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 4.14.83-gentoo (root@catalyst) #1 SMP Wed Jan 9 01:58:22 UTC 2019, RO-rootFS, swap_dev 0x3, Normal VGA
```

The kernel (bzImage). With Uefi, you just copy it to the ESP. Otherwise (MBR) to some dir and then grub-...,

---

**iso/isolinux/gentoo.igz**

The compressed initrd. With `xz` and `cpio -t` you can list:

```
]# xz -cd iso/isolinux/gentoo.igz | cpio -t lib/modu\* 
lib/modules
lib/modules/4.14.83-gentoo
lib/modules/4.14.83-gentoo/modules.order
lib/modules/4.14.83-gentoo/modules.symbols
...
```

---

There is a `grub/grub.cfg` on the iso.

```
menuentry 'Boot LiveCD (kernel: gentoo)' --class gnu-linux --class os {
    linux /isolinux/gentoo root=/dev/ram0 init=/linuxrc  dokeymap looptype=squashfs loop=/image.squashfs
    initrd /isolinux/gentoo.igz
```

After copying bash and the four libraries/dependencies (see `ldd` above) to a formatted partition `sdXY` you get these 3 boot arguments:

```
gentoo 
root=/dev/sdXY 
init=/bin/bash
initrd=gentoo.igz
```

---

Your points 3) and 4) (dirs and config files) are minor ones, for a minimal experiment. And if it is not-so-minimal, it amounts to creating a new distro...

Main difficulty is the boot process itself, simply because of the many possibilities, plus MBR vs. UEFI. I left out an init/systemd and login. Partitioning also, but that is (or should be, logically) detached from installation anyway. I left out everything, in fact, except /bin/bash.

---

This is a way to avoid the "classic assisted setup", and to do everything from scratch except compiling.

I took gentoo as an example just because it was suggested. The .iso files listed at the top are very similar, except the size. You can extract the binaries from any one of them, as shown.

Comment: UAU!!! thank you so much... great info... I'll try to follow your guidelines... and return here for any doubts... as I suspect your answer are a good candidate for a canonical answer on this subject... if I'm not imposing... I would dare to ask you for link the symbols/terms/items to the site you think has the best answers on the subject... for example.. "kernel" | "squashfs filesystem" | ...